# pyqtgraph mouse interaction: using mouse right or middle button to zoom to the selected box

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside2, pyqtgraph

in *pyqtgraph examples -> View Box Freatures*, we could use mouse interaction "left drag zoom to box" by setting `v2.setMouseMode(v2.RectMode)`

[image]

But this interaction is only available in one-button mouse mode. How could I modify the interaction, so that I can **in standard three-button mouse mode use right mouse button or middle mouse button** to zoom to the selected box?

Thank you all!

Comment: I don't get your question, because in both modes (PanMode and RectMode) the right mouse works the same, and the left mouse works equally to the middle mouse. Then the difference is: in **PanMode**, Left and Middle mouse work for drag; and in **RectMode**, Left and Middle mouse work for zoom a box.  See: https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/ViewBox/ViewBox.html#ViewBox.setMouseMode

Comment: @AlejandroCondori Hi the requirement is exactly in PanMode using middle mouse for zoom a box. By default zoom a box is only in RectMode. So I think I need to modify the `viewbox` class

Comment: Perfect, I was thinking you would want separate functions for the middle and left mouse, and, as you said, you need to modify the `viewbox` class. I will put my code below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ViewBox` class of `pyqtgraph` has only two "mouse modes":

- **PanMode**: Left and Middle mouse work for drag. Right mouse work for zoom in/out by drag.
- **RectMode**: Left and Middle mouse work to zoom the box. Right mouse work for zoom in/out by drag.

The reason why Left and Middle mouse works the same lays in the source code of the `ViewBox` class.
You want the Left mouse to drag the picture, the Middle mouse work to zoom the box and the Middle mouse work to zoom the box for zoom in/out by drag. My solution may be radical, but it works. I modified the class, using the source code as a model (source : [Pyqtgraph's ViewBox class](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/ViewBox/ViewBox.html)):

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import numpy as np

class ViewBox(pg.ViewBox):
    MyMode = 2
    def __init__(self):
        pg.ViewBox.__init__(self)
        
    def setMouseMode(self, mode):
        ## First we change this method to accept our new configuration
        if mode not in [ViewBox.PanMode, ViewBox.RectMode, ViewBox.MyMode]:
            raise Exception("Mode must be ViewBox.PanMode, ViewBox.RectMode or ViewBox.MyMode")
        self.state['mouseMode'] = mode
        self.sigStateChanged.emit(self)

    def mouseDragEvent(self, ev, axis=None):
        ev.accept()
        pos = ev.pos()
        lastPos = ev.lastPos()
        dif = pos - lastPos
        dif = dif * -1
        mouseEnabled = np.array(self.state['mouseEnabled'], dtype=np.float)
        mask = mouseEnabled.copy()
        if axis is not None:
            mask[1-axis] = 0.0

        ## Here is the main change for it to work    
        if ev.button() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            if self.state['mouseMode'] == ViewBox.RectMode and axis is None:
                if ev.isFinish():  ## This is the final move in the drag; change the view scale now
                    #print "finish"
                    self.rbScaleBox.hide()
                    ax = QtCore.QRectF(QtCore.QPointF(ev.buttonDownPos(ev.button())), QtCore.QPointF(pos))
                    ax = self.childGroup.mapRectFromParent(ax)
                    self.showAxRect(ax)
                    self.axHistoryPointer += 1
                    self.axHistory = self.axHistory[:self.axHistoryPointer] + [ax]
                else:
                    ## update shape of scale box
                    self.updateScaleBox(ev.buttonDownPos(), ev.pos())
            else:
                tr = self.childGroup.transform()
                tr = pg.functions.invertQTransform(tr)
                tr = tr.map(dif*mask) - tr.map(QtCore.QPointF(0,0))
                x = tr.x() if mask[0] == 1 else None
                y = tr.y() if mask[1] == 1 else None
                self._resetTarget()
                if x is not None or y is not None:
                    self.translateBy(x=x, y=y)
                self.sigRangeChangedManually.emit(self.state['mouseEnabled'])
        elif ev.button() & QtCore.Qt.MidButton:
            if self.state['mouseMode'] in {ViewBox.RectMode,ViewBox.MyMode} and axis is None:
                if ev.isFinish():  ## This is the final move in the drag; change the view scale now
                    #print "finish"
                    self.rbScaleBox.hide()
                    ax = QtCore.QRectF(QtCore.QPointF(ev.buttonDownPos(ev.button())), QtCore.QPointF(pos))
                    ax = self.childGroup.mapRectFromParent(ax)
                    self.showAxRect(ax)
                    self.axHistoryPointer += 1
                    self.axHistory = self.axHistory[:self.axHistoryPointer] + [ax]
                else:
                    ## update shape of scale box
                    self.updateScaleBox(ev.buttonDownPos(), ev.pos())
            else:
                tr = self.childGroup.transform()
                tr = pg.functions.invertQTransform(tr)
                tr = tr.map(dif*mask) - tr.map(QtCore.QPointF(0,0))
                x = tr.x() if mask[0] == 1 else None
                y = tr.y() if mask[1] == 1 else None
                self._resetTarget()
                if x is not None or y is not None:
                    self.translateBy(x=x, y=y)
                self.sigRangeChangedManually.emit(self.state['mouseEnabled'])
        elif ev.button() & QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            if self.state['aspectLocked'] is not False:
                mask[0] = 0
            dif = ev.screenPos() - ev.lastScreenPos()
            dif = np.array([dif.x(), dif.y()])
            dif[0] *= -1
            s = ((mask * 0.02) + 1) ** dif
            tr = self.childGroup.transform()
            tr = pg.functions.invertQTransform(tr)
            x = s[0] if mouseEnabled[0] == 1 else None
            y = s[1] if mouseEnabled[1] == 1 else None
            center = QtCore.QPointF(tr.map(ev.buttonDownPos(QtCore.Qt.RightButton)))
            self._resetTarget()
            self.scaleBy(x=x, y=y, center=center)
            self.sigRangeChangedManually.emit(self.state['mouseEnabled'])
```

We inherit Pyqtgraph's ViewBox class, and then change two methods:

- `setMouseMode()` for compatibility
- `mouseDragEvent` for the different function of the 3 clicks

Whit the class above you maintain the other two mouse modes as they are, but adding a new mode: `MyMode`.

Then instead of adding the `ViewBox` like this :

```
sub2 = win.addLayout()
sub2.addLabel("<b>One-button mouse interaction:</b><br>left-drag zoom to box, wheel to zoom out.")
sub2.nextRow()
v2 = sub2.addViewBox()
v2.setMouseMode(v2.RectMode)
l2 = pg.PlotDataItem(y)
v2.addItem(l2)
```

You should do it like this:

```
sub2 = win.addLayout()
sub2.addLabel("<b>One-button mouse interaction:</b><br>left-drag zoom to box, wheel to zoom out.")
sub2.nextRow()
v2 = ViewBox() ## This is our new class
sub2.addItem(v2)
v2.setMouseMode(v2.MyMode) ## Seting the new Mouse Mode
l2 = pg.PlotDataItem(y)
v2.addItem(l2)
```

I tested the code and did not found any issues, but I have to admit that the solution is a little bit exaggerated. I hope there is a simpler method.

***Edit***: The example is taken from *Pyqtgraph's examples* (ViewBox Features) ([Here](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#examples))

Comment: nice solution. Thanks a lot